# Taking android screen shot of whole screen

Tags: android

My application has a list view in relative layout. Now I need to take a screen shot of the entire layout including all the content available in the list view  and also other contents like button and text view showing in the layout. But my code takes only the visible part of the screen. Here the view is parent layout.

```
public void screen(){

     View v1 = findViewById(R.id.screenRoot);

    rel.layout(0, 0, rel.getMeasuredWidth(),rel.getMeasuredHeight());    
    View v = v1.getRootView();
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

   /* v.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(w, w), 
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(h, h));*/


//        v.layout(0, 0, rel.getWidth(), rel.getHeight());
    v.buildDrawingCache(true);

    System.out.println("rel "+rel.getHeight()+" "+v.getHeight());
    Bitmap b = v.getDrawingCache();  
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    String extr = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myPath = new File(extr, "tiket"+".jpg");
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(myPath);
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), b, "Screen", "screen");
        System.out.println("my path "+myPath+" "+fos);
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Captured Successfully", 0).show();

}
```

Comment: Capturing photo of a Scrolling window screen isn't possible. You can do capture only visible screen.

Comment: You can`t get the image of something that is`t drawn on the screen.

Comment: It is possible. I have done the same into my project.

Comment: @Bala any progress....??

Comment: yes @V.J as you said i tried this one, still it is working like before.....

Comment: i made this code for my acitivity to printing the current layout. and it's too long. and it is working very fine. nothing left.

Just put my code and call the function. for getting bitmap. i have added 3 lines before calling the function.

Comment: Update my code with storing captured image into the device.

Comment: @V.J.  v.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)); in this line the app get crashed...

Answer (score 1):

Call getBitmapFromView from your Click event or any thing.
R.id.root is my main RelativeLayout So you can pass you main layout.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
RelativeLayout root = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.youlayourfile,null);
root.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

Bitmap bmp = getBitmapFromView(this.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(R.id.root).getRootView());

URI uri = storPrintFile(bmp);
```

This function returns the Bitmap of your layout. Now you just need to store the bitmap into your device and anywhere else.

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View v) {
    v.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    v.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getMeasuredWidth(),
            v.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    v.draw(c);
    return b;       
}
```

Storing bitmap into device.

```
public URI storPrintFile(Bitmap bitmapToStore){
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
    String path = cw.getDir("CapturedImages",Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getPath();
    File file = new File(path);
    boolean isFileCreated = false;
    if (!file.exists()) {
        isFileCreated = file.mkdir();
        System.out.println("Directory created in Internal Storage is :" + path);
    }
    String current = "Screen.jpg";//uniqueId.replace(" ", "-").replace(":", "-") + ".jpeg";
    System.out.println("Internal Storage path is : " + current);
    File mypath = new File(file, current);
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
        bitmapToStore.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mypath.toURI();
}
```